# Wordpress hide pages in dashboard

Tags: wordpress, roles, capability

I want to know if there's a way to hide pages that do not belong to the logged in user in the dashboard?
I've been looking at capabilities, but as far as I can see I can only restrict interaction with pages not owned by the logged in user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new user role and define it's capabilities for the user roles.

```
add_role( 'photo_uploader', 'Photo Uploader', array( 'view_galleries' ) );
// remove "view_galleries" to this role object
$role->remove_cap( 'photo_uploader', 'view_galleries' );
```

Check more about custom user roles and capabilities [here](http://solislab.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/).

If you are looking for easier and faster solution you can do that using the following plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/members/

Comment: Hi I've been looking into this,but the problem is that I don't want to hide all pages from the user. Only ones not owned by him. So a capability won't work as it will block all pages from the user.

Comment: You can place a hook at the listing of the pages and change the query to only display pages created by the users.

add_filter('manage_event_posts_columns', 'bs_event_table_head');
function bs_event_table_head( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['author'] = 'Added By';
    return $defaults;
}

Comment: I might be missing something, but that array only has column headers in and does not allow me to change the page list. I looked at other filters and found get_pages() and wp_list_pages(). The former doesn't seem to get called on that specific page and the latter is an html list that would take a lot of string manipulation to do comparisons. Is there something I'm missing or something else I can look at?